# Mapping voronoi cell local space align perpendicular to a spherical surface?

Tags: transforms, volumetrics, procedural, vector-mapping, matrix

With blenders voronoi texture each cell has a local space. My goal is to use these voronoi cells to scatter a volumetric shader, like the volumetric gizmos below, with each volumetric cell instance oriented perpendicular to a spherical surface. The volumetric gizmos shown are each located within a voronoi cell and show the rotation of each accordingly.

I would ultimately prefer to use 3D voronoi as this method is seamless and does not create pinch points, which are present in my current work around. However, I am struggling to find a method that rotates each cells position to point the Z axis upwards from the surface. The references below show the basic 3D voronoi cell positions, with each of these cells local space oriented in accordance with the host objects local space.

3D view with volumetric gizmos:
[image: 3D Voronoi local cell position]

Shader node tree for isolating cell local positions:
[image: Shader layout for standard 3D noise]

My current solution is far from perfect, utilizing voronoi that is radially wrapped around a sphere, it succeeds in aligning the cell positions perpendicular to the spherical surface; However, Significant problems occur, namely in a very obvious vertical seam and pinch points on the poles.

3D view of work around with volumetric gizmos:
[image: Work Around for aligning cell direction]

Shader node tree for the work around system:
[image: Shader layout for current work around]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.